# linux error with libc.so.6

Tags: c++, linux

I compiled a c++ program on my ubuntu 12.04 machine and am attempting to run it on a red hat linux server. When I run it on the server I get this error:

> /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found

I found the libc.so.6 file and found it was linked to libc-2_12.so in the same directory. I assume I need to replace the libc-2_12.so file with one like libc-2_14.so. But through searching I found no way of doing it or if it is even possible. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Confirm this: your redhat linux server is 32bit right? If its 64bit, the path to the LDLIBRARY is different from ubuntu?

Comment: both machines are 64 bit

Comment: are compiler version and hardware architecture the same on both machines?

Comment: RedHat is made for being "stable", which means that each release basically only get security fixes. This means that most of the packages are not up to date like in a distribution with rolling releases or at least more frequent releases like Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, the best way is to recompile your program for RedHat.
In RH the only way to replace that file is to recompile the whole libc, but it will destroy all other software installed with RH. RH's packaging system does not allow you to switch between different versions of libc.

Comment: Ok, I was afraid of that, I'll attempt to build it on the server. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the correct library somewhere on your red hat cluster (otherwise get a valid one), simply add its path to the front of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (`LD_RUN_PATH` may also do).

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have said, the best way is to just re-compile your program on the server. Another way could be to statically link your program, by passing `-static` to GCC when linking (or, if you're just compiling with a single command, when compiling your program).

This should pull in all dependencies and create a single, albeit quite large, program, rather than using the dynamic linker at run time. There's all sorts of behaviour that can go wrong though, so you may end up with strange behaviour, or nothing useful at all. **Use with caution**.

Of course, this will only work if both machines are of the same architecture.